# USB-Stick Encrypted for a period of time + Load data on it in this period of time?

Tags: usb, memory, security, encryption, disk-encryption

For a study, where I am required to store data for a period of time without the possibility to see them I need a solution for a USB-Stick.

Is there a possible way to:

1. Have an encrypted USB-Stick
2. Drag and drop data from a computer to the encrypted USB-Stick (this is done by the participants of the study not by me) (ideally, the participant should also not see what is on the USB-Stick, e.g., only a folder "drag your files here"). Important here: The USB-Stick should not be required to unlock every time it is plugged into the USB-Port (because we have several participants, and we don't know the password of the USB-Stick). Just plug it in and drag the file to the USB-Stick, then the files are encrypted.
3. It should not be possible for me to open the USB-Stick afterwards and see this files. Imagine a "black hole" (the USB-Stick), where I can drag files in, but afterwards I cannot see or open them.
4. The data on the USB-Stick should be encrypted/locked for a specific period of time. After this period I should be able to see the data put onto this "black hole" (USB-Stick) normally.

Thanks for any advises, and thanks for helping to solve this tricky puzzle

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to create a timelocked encryption.  But why couldn't you be emailed the key when the time is up?

Comment: This could be a possible solution for the timelocked encryption. But then again the question is, who gets the key? ...but this could be handeled. Are all other requirements possible? e.g., the insta encryption of new files dragged to the usb stick?

Comment: So you want to write your own program, that will black-box files and not show them to anyone until after a certain date? Programming is more on topic at Stack Overflow